# How can I re-enter "Fragile Existence" (level 9) after I changed it into Baba?

Tags: baba-is-you

While playing level 9 ("Fragile Existence") I accidentally spelled `Level Is Baba` and got back to the world map with said level replaced by Baba:

[image: Current situation]

Now I cannot enter the level again, as Baba moves away as soon as I try to enter the level:

[image: Baba runs away]

But I haven't solved the level yet! How can I re-enter the level?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to reenter "Fragile Existence" (level 9), you have to satisfy two conditions:

- the cursor must be on top of the level (in this case Baba)
- the cursor must not be on top of another map element, e.g. another level or the path

At first, this seems like an impossible condition. However, the cursor can move on-top of Baba **off the path**. Or to use game terms:

- `CURSOR ON BABA AND NOT ON PATH IS ENTER`.
- `CURSOR ON BABA IS WALKABLE`

So in order to play the level, you have to move Baba to the cursor and then move *away* from the path. The easiest way is to go into level 8 ("Slideshow") and then back to the map. Afterwards, move down, right and then left:

[image: Solving the conundrum]

Comment: You can change the level back into a stationary map icon by spelling `LEVEL IS KEY`.

Comment: @StevenM.Vascellaro True, but that's a hen and egg problem: to be able to change it into a stationary map icon, you first need to enter the level :). (Also, you really want a Baba on that screen later in the game).